# NN on the test sample shows the correct answers, but when I give my data, she is ALWAYS wrong

Tags: deep-learning, tf.keras

I solved the problem of recognizing handwritten numbers using the Internet. It gave correct answers and had an accuracy of ~97.5%. But I wanted to test it on my own data. In this case, she was always wrong.  I first gave her a photo of the numbers from the paper (using Opencv, I scaled them, made them gray). Having received an unsatisfactory result, I began to "feed" her the numbers from Paint.) But in the end, the result remained unsatisfied.

Photo fraud:

```
image = cv2.imread("22.png")

gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gray_image = cv2.resize(gray_image, (28, 28), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

print(gray_image.shape)
cv2_imshow(gray_image)
```

Launch code NN:

```
x = np.expand_dims(gray_image, axis=0)
res = model.predict(x)
print( res )
print( np.argmax(res) )
```

[Also, I attach the data that I gave to NN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNEWg.png)
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xn62g.png) [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSb9y.png) [and Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQiK3.png)

According to NN - all this is equal to 5

I tried to train the neural network better, change the data, change the code. But it didn't affect anything.

I have a place in my code where I take a photo from the Mnist database and see what NN saw in this photo. I tried to take the same code and overlay it on my data. It didn't work.

This is the place:

```
n = 36
x = np.expand_dims(x_test[n], axis=0)
res = model.predict(x)
print( res )
print( np.argmax(res) )
plt.imshow(x_test[n], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
plt.show()
```

Please tell me what to do so that NN could correctly recognize the numbers on my photos. Thanks

Comment: Was the model trained on images with white background and black text, or the other way around? If your input does not match what the model is trained on then you will find that your model will have very poor predictive power.

Comment: @mhovd You were right. I didn't take into account that she was trained on white numbers on top of a black background. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you perform machine learning or any form of prediction, you have to make sure that your model is trained on data that is similar to the data you want to perform predictions on. Here I assume that you trained on data with a black background and white text, like the MNIST set.

Therefore, you should invert the input data so that it is similar to that you have trained the model on.